# can not start greengrassd (AWS IOT greengrass) on raspberrypi

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I have register AWS IoT Greengrass group.

I also download Greengrass certificate from console and [AmazonRoot-CA1](https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem)

here is list my certificate files(store in /greengrass/certs/):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1220 Jan 15 10:07 82ab16xxxx.cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1679 Jan 15 10:07 82ab16xxxx.private.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  451 Jan 15 10:07 82ab16xxxx.public.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1188 Jan 15 10:07 root.ca.pem
```

When I start greengrassd by command:

```
sudo ./greengrassd start
```

I have error:

```
Setting up greengrass daemon
Validating hardlink/softlink protection
Waiting for up to 40s for Daemon to start
Error occured while generating TLS config: ErrUnknownURIScheme: no handlers matched for path: .../greengrass/certs/root.ca.pem
The Greengrass daemon process with [pid = 18029] died
```

I have try to re-install OS but still error.

I also install mosquitto-clients and mosquitto on raspberrypi

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is that you haven't activated your root CA from the console.

try this instead:

sudo wget -O root.ca.pem https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem

try doing this directly in your certs directory then restarting your deamon.